# Trying to create a couple of triggers

Tags: mysql, triggers

Good morning.
I'm new in the world of mysql (in my case MariaDB) triggers.
May I ask some help with this triggers? I'm using PHPMyadmin's SQL prompt line.
I have a table called 'Coches'(cars) and a table 'Alquileres'(rents)
I want the rents to be actualized with some values of the table coches (the price per day of the car) and to automatically calculate the price of the rent of the car.

```
table : Alquileres 
+-------+-----------+-----------+---------+---------+--------+
|   id  |   fechi   |   fechf   |   prd   |   prf   |  matr  |
+-------+-----------+-----------+---------+---------+--------+
|   1   | 02/02/2020|03/02/2020 |   80    |   160   |  11e45 |
|   2   | 02/05/2020|    null   |   55    |   null  |  41y45 |
|   3   | 02/07/2021|03/07/2020 |   214   |   428   |  34t56 |
|   4   | 02/01/2020|    null   |   81    |   null  |  22r16 |
|   5   | 02/05/2021|02/05/2021 |   214   |   214   |  34t56 |
+-------+-----------+-----------+---------+---------+--------+

> //`feci` is the starting date of the rent 
> //`fecf` is the end date of the rent 
> //`prd` is the priceperday 
> //`prf` is the final price of the rent
> //`matr` is plate number

table: coches
+-------+-----------+-----------+
|   id  |   matr    |   prd     |
+-------+-----------+-----------+
|   1   |   11e45   |    80     | 
|   2   |   41y45   |    55     | 
|   3   |   34t56   |    214    |
|   4   |   22r16   |    81     | 
+-------+-----------+-----------+
```

The first trigger is a BEFORE INSERT to retrieve some values from the table coches.
Here is what I tried:

```
CREATE TRIGGER preciodiario
BEFORE INSERT ON Alquileres
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET new.prd = (SELECT Coches.prd FROM Coches WHERE Coches.mat = new.mat)
END
```

and
[Here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZyMN.jpg)
trad:#1064 - Something is wrong in your syntax near 'END' on line 6

The second update is an AFTER UPDATE. I have a little idea about that but here is what I tried:

```
CREATE TRIGGER calculoautomatico 
BEFORE UPDATE ON Alquileres 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN   
    IF new.fecf IS NOT NULL   
    THEN SET new.prf = (datediff(Alquileres.feci,new.fecf)+1)*Alquileres.prd 
    END IF
END
```

and
[Here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRuni.jpg)
trad:   #1064 - Something is wrong in your syntax near 'END IF'
END' on line 7

Comment: Every statement needs to be terminated..every if needs a then an end if

Comment: BTW publishing the errors in English on an English site is helpful as is publishing as text

Comment: ```SET `prf` = (datediff(`feci`,`fecf`)+1)*prd``` - what is `prf` which you want to set? in what table, in what row? now it will be treated as (undeclared) local variable.

Comment: In the second trigger all the `prf` is the final price and is into the same table. no external table apart from alquileres is involved

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5 and #3.

Comment: @Akina hope my edits helps to understand better

Comment: @P.Salmon sorry,my server is in spanish. I added translations for the errors

Comment: *hope my edits helps to understand better* Your editions must help not to understand but to reproduce. So you must provide CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO which creates your table(s) with data, action queries if needed, and desired output or final data state for this source data.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

If we try to put this code in a sql statement in phpMyAdmin and execute it as it is, it will give us problems with the separators of the manager itself.

Let me explain, phpMyAdmin uses the character ";" as a separator by default, and if we look at the statement we have used that character as statement finalizer because the MySQL server requires it.

So, this is where the most IMPORTANT part and the thing that gave me the most headaches, and it's something as simple as changing the phpMyAdmin delimiter in the text box just below the text box where we introduce the SQL query.

It's as simple as changing the value of that text box (which is now ";") to the value "//".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).